# D3.js node links overflowing into sibling nodes when new nodes are being added

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am working on a D3.js V4/5 implementation of building a vertical flow-chart. I am adding a new node to the flow-chart's decision box by clicking on a "decision" box and it's corresponding "diamond"/"rect" shape.

From Mike Bostocks answer here for adding/removing nodes :- https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/issues/139
I've followed step 1 which is :- "Derive an entirely new tree by calling d3.hierarchy after modifying your data (or passing in a different children accessor function to do filtering".

So when a user tries to add a new node I am modifying the actual tree/children , computing the hierarchy and calling the update() method. Something like below

JS Fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/rs3owt6g/6/

```
function updateAfterAddingNode() {  
  root = d3.hierarchy(treeData[0], function(d) {
      return d.children;
    });
    root.x0 = height/2;
    root.y0 = 0;
    
    update(root);
}
```

**Actual Issue:**

Everything seems to be working fine until the point when I try to add 2 decision nodes to a decision node and more decision nodes underneath it. The Links connecting the nodes passes through the other sibling node.

To replicate the issue in fiddle:

To add a new node click on the orange diamond which appears on click of a node.

[image]

Add 2 sibling nodes ( 1 action/rect and 1 decision node) to left and right respectively. For the decision node add 2 decision nodes and for these 2 decision nodes add another 2 decison nodes.

Below picture can give you a clarity. As you can see, the left highlighted path goes through the "New Action" node instead of staying put at the earlier location when all nodes are added. Also, the distance between siblings grows a lot more when more children are added.

[image]

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120,
  },
  width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

function generateEmptyDecisionBox(condition) {
  return condition === 'False' ? [{
    "name": "newDecision",
    "id": "newId",
    "type": "decision",
    "value": "notSure",
    "condition": `${condition}`,
  }, {}] : [{}, {
    "name": "newDecision",
    "id": "newId",
    "type": "decision",
    "value": "notSure",
    "condition": `${condition}`,
  }];
}

function generateEmptyActionBox(condition) {
  return condition === 'False' ? [{
    "name": "newAction",
    "id": "newId",
    "type": "action",
    "value": "notSure",
    "condition": `${condition}`,
  }, {}] : [{}, {
    "name": "newAction",
    "id": "newId",
    "type": "action",
    "value": "notSure",
    "condition": `${condition}`,
  }];
}

var selectedNode;
var selectedLink;


   var treeData = [{
  "name": "Root",
  "type": "decision",
  "id": "root",
  "children": [{
      "name": "analytics",
      "condition": "False",
      "type": "decision",
      "value": "a+b",
      "id": "child1",
      "children": [{
        "name": "distinction",
        "type": "action",
        "id": "child2",
        "condition": "True",
        "value": "5",
      }, {
        "name": "nonDistinction",
        "type": "action",
        "id": "child3",
        "condition": "False",
        "value": "4",
        "children": [],
      }],
    },
    {
      "condition": "True",
      "name": "division",
      "type": "decision",
      "value": "a-b",
      "id": "child33",
      "children":[{
      "condition": "True",
      "name": "division1",
      "type": "decision",
      "value": "a-b",
      "id": "child44",
      "children":[{
      "condition": "True",
      "name": "division1.1",
      "type": "decision",
      "value": "a-b",
      "id": "child599",
      "children":[{
      "condition": "True",
      "name": "division1.1.34",
      "type": "decision",
      "value": "a-b",
      "id": "child234234",
      "children":[{
      "condition": "True",
      "name": "division1.1.434",
      "type": "decision",
      "value": "a-b",
      "id": "child35343",
      "children":[],
      }],
     },{
      "condition": "True",
      "name": "division1.1.2",
      "type": "decision",
      "value": "a-b",
      "id": "child77",
      "children":[{
      "condition": "True",
      "name": "division1.1.1",
      "type": "decision",
      "value": "a-b",
      "id": "child1222",
      "children":[],
      },{
      "condition": "True",
      "name": "division1.1.1",
      "type": "decision",
      "value": "a-b",
      "id": "child66",
      "children":[],
      }],
     }],
     },{
       "condition": "True",
      "name": "NODE HAVING OVERLAP ISSUE",
      "type": "decision",
      "value": "a-b",
      "id": "child9090",
      "children":[],
     }],
     },
     {
      "condition": "True",
      "name": "division2",
      "type": "decision",
      "value": "a-b",
      "id": "child55",
      "children":[{
      "condition": "True",
      "name": "division2.1",
      "type": "decision",
      "value": "a-b",
      "id": "child88",
      "children":[{
      "condition": "True",
      "name": "division2.1.1",
      "type": "decision",
      "value": "a-b",
      "id": "child99",
      "children":[],
     }],
     }],
     },
     ],
     },
  ],
}];
var i = 0,
  duration = 1000,
  rectW = 120,
  rectH = 60;

var treeMap = d3.tree()
  .nodeSize([150, 180]);

//LINK FUNCTION TO DRAW LINKS
var linkFunc = function(d) {
  var source = {
    x: d.parent.x + rectW / 2,
    y: d.parent.y + (rectH / 2),
  };
  var target = {
    x: d.x + (rectW / 2),
    y: d.y + 3,
  };

  // This is where the line bends
  var inflection = {
    x: target.x,
    y: source.y,
  };
  var radius = 5;

  var result = "M" + source.x + ',' + source.y;

  if (source.x < target.x && d.data.type) {
    // Child is to the right of the parent
    result += ' H' + (inflection.x - radius);
  } else if (d.data.type) {
    result += ' H' + (inflection.x + radius);
  } else {
    return;
  }

  // Curve the line at the bend slightly
  result += ' Q' + inflection.x + ',' + inflection.y + ' ' + inflection.x + ',' + (inflection.y + radius);

  result += 'V' + target.y;
  return result;
};

// END OF LINK FUNC //

const zoomSvg = d3.select('.tree-diagram')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .append('g');

const svg = zoomSvg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 300 + ',' + 20 + ')');

const attachZoom = d3.select('svg');
attachZoom.call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', () => {
  zoomSvg.attr('transform', d3.event.transform)
}))


// ADD ARROW TO THE BOTTOM POINTING TO THE NEXT DECISION.

svg.append("svg:defs")
  .selectAll("marker")
  .data(["end"]) // Different link/path types can be defined here
  .enter()
  .append("svg:marker") // This section adds in the arrows
  .attr("id", String)
  .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
  .attr("refX", 15)
  .attr("refY", 0.5)
  .attr("markerWidth", 4)
  .attr("markerHeight", 4)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

//necessary so that zoom knows where to zoom and unzoom from
/* zm.translate([350, 20]); */

root = d3.hierarchy(treeData[0], function(d) {
  return d.children;
});
root.x0 = 0;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

d3.select(".tree-diagram")
  .style("height", "1000px");

// END OF DRAW TREEE //

function update(source) {
  const treeData = treeMap(root);
  const treeRoot = d3.hierarchy(root);
  //  d3.tree(treeRoot);
  // var treeData = treeMap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
    links = treeData.descendants()
    .slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 90;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.data.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + source.x0 + ', ' + source.y0 + ')')
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("click", click);
  //  .on("blur", onNodeBlur);

  nodeEnter.append('path')
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      if (d.data.type === 'decision') {
        return 'M 60 0 120 30 60 60 0 30 Z';
      } else if (d.data.type === 'action') {
        return 'M 0 0 120 0 120 60 0 60 Z';
      } else {
        return 'M -100 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10Z';
      }
    })
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr('class', 'myPaths')
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return "lightsteelblue";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", rectW / 2)
    .attr("y", rectH / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name;
    });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (d.x) + "," + (d.y) + ")";
    });


  nodeUpdate.select('path.myPaths')
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      if (d.data.type === 'decision') {
        return 'M 60 0 120 30 60 60 0 30 Z';
      } else if (d.data.type === 'action') {
        return 'M 0 0 120 0 120 60 0 60 Z';
      } else {
        return 'M -100 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10Z';
      }
    });


  var nodeExit = node.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.data.id;
    })
    .classed('link1', true);


  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter()
    .insert("g", "g")
    .attr("class", "link");

  linkEnter.append('path')
    .on('click', function(d, i) {
      selectedLink = d;
      // Use the native SVG interface to get the bounding box to
      // calculate the center of the path

      var bbox = this.getBBox();
      var x;
      var y;

      if (d.parent.x < d.x) {
        // Child is to the right of the parent
        x = bbox.x + bbox.width;
        y = bbox.y;
        plusButton
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ', ' + y + ')')
          .classed('hide', false);

      } else {
        x = bbox.x;
        y = bbox.y;
        plusButton
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ', ' + y + ')')
          .classed('hide', false);
      }
    })
    .on('blur', function(d, i) {
      plusButton
        .classed('hide', true);
    })
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

  // Add Link Texts.
  linkEnter.append('text');

  // Merge the new and the existing links before setting `d` and `text` on all of them
  link = linkEnter.merge(link);

  link.select('path')
    .attr("d", linkFunc);

  link.select('text')
    .text(function(d, i) {
      if (d.parent.x < d.x) {
        return 'True';
      } else {
        return 'False';
      }
    })
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
      if (d.parent.x < d.x && d.data.type) {
        return 'translate(' + (d.x + rectW / 2) + ',' + (d.parent.y + rectH) + ')';
      } else if (d.data.type) {
        return 'translate(' + (d.parent.x + rectW / 2) + ',' + (d.y + rectH) + ')';
      } else {
        return;
      }
    });


  //LinkUpdate
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", linkFunc);

  // Transition links to their new position.

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", linkFunc)
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}


// ON CLICK OF NODES
function click(d) {

  if (d.data.type === 'action') {
    return;
  }

  selectedNode = d;

  if (!(d.data.children && d.data.children[0] && Object.keys(d.data.children[0]).length)) {
    diamondImageFalse
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (d.x - 20) + ', ' + (d.y + 35) + ')')
      .classed('hide', false);

    rectangleShapeFalse.attr('transform', 'translate(' + (d.x - 20) + ', ' + d.y + ')').classed('hide', false);

  }

  if (!(d.data.children && d.data.children[1] && Object.keys(d.data.children[1]).length)) {
    diamondImage
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (d.x + 110) + ', ' + (d.y + 35) + ')')
      .classed('hide', false);

    rectangleShape.attr('transform', 'translate(' + (d.x + 110) + ', ' + d.y + ')').classed('hide', false);

  }
}

// oN CALL

function addElement(d, truthy) {
  d.children = null;
  d.children = generateEmptyDecisionBox(truthy);
  update(root);
}

// draw elements //

function drawDiamond(centroid) {
  // Start at the top
  var result = 'M' + centroid.x + ',' + (centroid.y - rectH / 2);

  // Go right
  result += 'L' + (centroid.x + rectW / 2) + ',' + centroid.y;

  // Bottom
  result += 'L' + centroid.x + ',' + (centroid.y + rectH / 2);

  // Left
  result += 'L' + (centroid.x - rectW / 2) + ',' + centroid.y;

  // Close the shape
  result += 'Z';

  return result;
}

function drawRect(centroid) {
  // Start at the top left
  var result = 'M' + (centroid.x - rectW / 2) + ',' + (centroid.y - rectH / 2);

  // Go right
  result += 'h' + rectW;

  // Go down
  result += 'v' + rectH;

  // Left
  result += 'h-' + rectW;

  // Close the shape
  result += 'Z';
  return result;
}

var plusButton = svg
  .append('g')
  .classed('button', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    /*        addElement(selectedLink.source); */
    removeAllButtonElements();
  });

plusButton
  .append('rect')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(-8, -8)') // center the button inside the `g`
  .attr('width', 16)
  .attr('height', 16)
  .attr('rx', 2);

plusButton
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', 'M-6 0 H6 M0 -6 V6');

var rectangleShape = svg.append('g')
  .classed('conditionImage', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    addActionOrDecision(selectedNode, 'action', 'True');
    removeAllButtonElements();
  });

rectangleShape
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', 30)
  .attr('height', 20)
  .style('fill', 'orange');


var diamondImage = svg.append('g')
  .classed('conditionSvg', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .classed('scale', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    addActionOrDecision(selectedNode, 'decision', 'True');
    removeAllButtonElements();
  });

diamondImage
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', 'M 15 0 30 15 15 30 0 15 Z')
  .style("fill", 'orange');


var rectangleShapeFalse = svg.append('g')
  .classed('conditionImage', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    addActionOrDecision(selectedNode, 'action', 'False');
    removeAllButtonElements();
  });

rectangleShapeFalse
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', 30)
  .attr('height', 20)
  .style('fill', 'orange');

var diamondImageFalse = svg.append('g')
  .classed('conditionImage', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .classed('scale', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    addActionOrDecision(selectedNode, 'decision', 'False');
    //  addElement(selectedNode, 'False');
    removeAllButtonElements();
  });

diamondImageFalse
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', 'M 15 0 30 15 15 30 0 15 Z')
  .style("fill", 'orange');


function removeAllButtonElements() {
  plusButton.classed('hide', true);
  diamondImage.classed('hide', true);
  rectangleShape.classed('hide', true);
  diamondImageFalse.classed('hide', true);
  rectangleShapeFalse.classed('hide', true);
}


function addActionOrDecision(selectedNode, nodeType, conditionType) {

  const parentNodeId = selectedNode.parent.data.id;
  const selectedNodeId = selectedNode.data.id;

  // find the selected node from the actual treeData
  const foundRule = getNodeFromNodeId(treeData, selectedNodeId);
  const newRuleId = Math.random();

  const newNodeToAdd = {
    "condition": conditionType,
    "name": nodeType === 'decision' ? 'New Decision' : 'New Action',
    "type": nodeType,
    "value": "",
    "id": newRuleId,
    "parent": parentNodeId,
    "children": [],
  };

  const clonedNewNode = { ...newNodeToAdd
  };

  if (conditionType === 'False' && foundRule.children) {
    //    foundRule.children[0] = newNodeToAdd;

    foundRule.children.splice(0, 1, clonedNewNode);

    if (!(foundRule.children[1] && Object.keys(foundRule.children[1]))) {
      foundRule.children[1] = {};
    }

  } else {
    //   foundRule.children[1] = newNodeToAdd;

    foundRule.children.splice(1, 1, clonedNewNode);

    if (!(foundRule.children[0] && Object.keys(foundRule.children[0]))) {
      founRule.children[0] = {};
    }
  }

  // find the node and add a child to it. 
  updateTree();

}

function updateTree() {
  root = d3.hierarchy(treeData[0], function(d) {
    return d.children;
  });
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  update(root);

}

function getNodeFromNodeId(nodes, nodeId) {
  for (const node of nodes) {
    const currNode = node;
    if (currNode) {
      if (currNode.id === nodeId) {
        return currNode;
      } else if (currNode.children) {
        const childResult = getNodeFromNodeId(currNode.children, nodeId);
        if (childResult) {
          return childResult;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none !important;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.button>path {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 1.5;
  /*   outline: none;  */
}

.button>rect {
  fill: #ddd;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.conditionalSvg {
  /*   outline: none; */
  display: none;
}

.hide {
  /*    display: none;  */
  opacity: 0 !important;
  /*  pointer-events: none;  */
}

.link:hover {
  outline: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.link path {
  /*   outline: none !important;  */
  fill: none;
  stroke: darkgray;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.link path:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}

.link text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.colorBlue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="tree-diagram">
</div>
```

Also just wanted to take a confirmation on the way the nodes are being added in the `addActionOrDecision`  let me know if that's a good way to do it. I am basically finding the parent node from the actual data and adding a copy of a newly created node to the parent node's children ( in the actual treeData ).

Edit :- This is how it looks when I keep adding more nodes , the left side's nodes are mixed up with the right side one's and the nodes/links are messed up.

[image]

UX on how it should probably look like :- (Add a bend to the link and adjust the entire tree to the left or right accordingly ? )

[image]

EDIT :-

`Modified JsFiddle to show the issue during the initial launch :-` http://jsfiddle.net/c3yz4bj0/3/

[image]

Comment: So, ideally I believe the other tree items should adjust depending on the position where the node is being added i.e. if the tree finds that the newly added node's  d.x property is is lesser than or greater than the sibling's d.x property the node should not transition from it's current place ? the entire tree should adjust and draw ? Not quite sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Adding a bend to the link would raise a new issue: what if the node the link is now avoiding gets a child? Then it would overlap with the other nodes

Comment: @Ruben Helsloot, Yeah you are right,  that's surely is an issue.  may be the tree should figure out somehow that there are nodes beneath it ? Not quite sure how to achieve this.

Comment: check this http://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I was just taking a look at this Org chart :-  https://bl.ocks.org/bumbeishvili/09a03b81ae788d2d14f750afe59eb7de . Implementation looks scary for a beginner like me :/ But looks like this is doing something similar while adding one of the nodes, the chart sees that there is already a link draw below and adjusts accordingly. Not quite sure how I can achieve this with my current d3.js diagram. :/

Comment: Should it be that the tree should actually know that there's already a link/node beneath it and it should resize itself, Am I doing something wrong with my code ? Because in other org chart that I pasted in my above comment, there is one point where the while adding the tree knows that there is a link/nodes beneath it and adjusts itself accordingly. Please suggest , I am stuck here.

Comment: Your snippet seems broken, clicking the plus button does not do anything. I have an idea on how to help you, but can't verify it easily without working code

Comment: @Ruben Helsloot Sorry, I've not added any logic for the plus button in the reproducer, if you want to add a new decision node, please click on the "right bottom orange diamond" which appears when you click a node. In the following fiddle I changed the tree Data itself to replicate this issue during the initial launch http://jsfiddle.net/c3yz4bj0/3/  ( The node with the name "NODE HAVING OVERLAP ISSUE" is the one with the issue. I will also update the question with the latest fiddle link. Please let me know if you want me to add the logic for the + button to add a node in between?

Comment: @RubenHelsloot Did you get a chance to look at this ? One thing that I observed while trying to find out a solution for this is - for the node that is overlapping, if I add an empty children key with an empty object in it - say " children: [ {} ] " the tree is able to figure out and readjust itself but the issue here is the distance between sibling nodes is growing far greater than expected and the flow chart is bulging up width wise. Could you please take some time to provide your solution that you have in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by writing a custom [`tree.separation()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/v1.1.9/README.md#tree_separation) function. It's very similar to the [default one](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/src/tree.js#L3), but differs in that it places nodes farther apart if only one of the two nodes has any children. This prevents the overlap. Normally, if two nodes both have children, those children will be the reason why they are not overlapping, but sometimes this doesn't work.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120,
  },
  width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

function generateEmptyDecisionBox(condition) {
  return condition === 'False' ? [{
    "name": "newDecision",
    "id": "newId",
    "type": "decision",
    "value": "notSure",
    "condition": `${condition}`,
  }, {}] : [{}, {
    "name": "newDecision",
    "id": "newId",
    "type": "decision",
    "value": "notSure",
    "condition": `${condition}`,
  }];
}

function generateEmptyActionBox(condition) {
  return condition === 'False' ? [{
    "name": "newAction",
    "id": "newId",
    "type": "action",
    "value": "notSure",
    "condition": `${condition}`,
  }, {}] : [{}, {
    "name": "newAction",
    "id": "newId",
    "type": "action",
    "value": "notSure",
    "condition": `${condition}`,
  }];
}

var selectedNode;
var selectedLink;


var treeData = [{
  "name": "Root",
  "type": "decision",
  "id": "root",
  "children": [{
      "name": "analytics",
      "condition": "False",
      "type": "decision",
      "value": "a+b",
      "id": "child1",
      "children": [{
        "name": "distinction",
        "type": "action",
        "id": "child2",
        "condition": "True",
        "value": "5",
      }, {
        "name": "nonDistinction",
        "type": "action",
        "id": "child3",
        "condition": "False",
        "value": "4",
        "children": [],
      }],
    },
    {
      "condition": "True",
      "name": "division",
      "type": "decision",
      "value": "a-b",
      "id": "child33",
      "children": [{
          "condition": "True",
          "name": "division1",
          "type": "decision",
          "value": "a-b",
          "id": "child44",
          "children": [{
            "condition": "True",
            "name": "division1.1",
            "type": "decision",
            "value": "a-b",
            "id": "child599",
            "children": [{
              "condition": "True",
              "name": "division1.1.34",
              "type": "decision",
              "value": "a-b",
              "id": "child234234",
              "children": [{
                "condition": "True",
                "name": "division1.1.434",
                "type": "decision",
                "value": "a-b",
                "id": "child35343",
                "children": [],
              }],
            }, {
              "condition": "True",
              "name": "division1.1.2",
              "type": "decision",
              "value": "a-b",
              "id": "child77",
              "children": [{
                "condition": "True",
                "name": "division1.1.1",
                "type": "decision",
                "value": "a-b",
                "id": "child1222",
                "children": [],
              }, {
                "condition": "True",
                "name": "division1.1.1",
                "type": "decision",
                "value": "a-b",
                "id": "child66",
                "children": [],
              }],
            }],
          }, {
            "condition": "True",
            "name": "NODE HAVING OVERLAP ISSUE",
            "type": "decision",
            "value": "a-b",
            "id": "child9090",
            "children": [{
                "condition": "True",
                "name": "division1.1.1",
                "type": "decision",
                "value": "a-b",
                "id": "child909090",
                "children": [],
              }],
          }],
        },
        {
          "condition": "True",
          "name": "division2",
          "type": "decision",
          "value": "a-b",
          "id": "child55",
          "children": [{
            "condition": "True",
            "name": "division2.1",
            "type": "decision",
            "value": "a-b",
            "id": "child88",
            "children": [{
              "condition": "True",
              "name": "division2.1.1",
              "type": "decision",
              "value": "a-b",
              "id": "child99",
              "children": [],
            }],
          }],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}];
var i = 0,
  duration = 1000,
  rectW = 120,
  rectH = 60;

var treeMap = d3.tree()
  .nodeSize([140, 120])
  .separation(function(a, b) {
    // If they have the same parent
    if(a.parent === b.parent) {
      // and are either both leaf nodes or both not leaf nodes
      // or have only one child (which results in a straight line down)
      if((a.children === undefined || a.children.length <= 1) ===
         (b.children === undefined || b.children.length <= 1)) {
        return 1;
      }
      // else, increase the size between them
      return 2;
    }
    
    // If they have the same depth, mark them as such so we can avoid them later
    if(a.depth === b.depth) {
      a.data.avoidRight = b;
      b.data.avoidLeft = a;
    }
    return 2;
  });

//LINK FUNCTION TO DRAW LINKS
var linkFunc = function(d) {
  var source = {
    x: d.source.x + rectW / 2,
    y: d.source.y + (rectH / 2),
  };
  var target = {
    x: d.target.x + (rectW / 2),
    y: d.target.y + 3,
  };

  // This is where the line bends
  var inflection = {
    x: target.x,
    y: source.y,
  };
  var radius = 5;

  var result = "M" + source.x + ',' + source.y;

  if(!d.source.data.type) {
    return;
  }
  if(source.x < target.x) {
    // Child is to the right of the parent
    if(d.source.data.avoidRight !== undefined && inflection.x > d.source.data.avoidRight.x) {
      // There is some node that we should try to avoid first
      result += ' H' + (d.source.data.avoidRight.x - 2 * radius);
      result += ' V' + (d.source.data.avoidRight.y + rectH + radius);
      inflection.y = d.source.data.avoidLeft.y + rectH + radius;
    }

    result += ' H' + (inflection.x - radius);
  } else {
    // Child is to the left of parent
    if(d.source.data.avoidLeft !== undefined && inflection.x < d.source.data.avoidLeft.x + rectW) {
      result += ' H' + (d.source.data.avoidLeft.x + rectW + 2 * radius);
      result += ' V' + (d.source.data.avoidLeft.y + rectH + radius);
      inflection.y = d.source.data.avoidLeft.y + rectH + radius;
    }

    result += ' H' + (inflection.x + radius);
  }

  // Curve the line at the bend slightly
  result += ' Q' + inflection.x + ',' + inflection.y + ' ' + inflection.x + ',' + (inflection.y + radius);

  result += 'V' + target.y;
  return result;
};

// END OF LINK FUNC //

const zoomSvg = d3.select('.tree-diagram')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .append('g');

const svg = zoomSvg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 300 + ',' + 20 + ')');

const attachZoom = d3.select('svg');
attachZoom.call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', () => {
  zoomSvg.attr('transform', d3.event.transform)
}))


// ADD ARROW TO THE BOTTOM POINTING TO THE NEXT DECISION.

svg.append("svg:defs")
  .selectAll("marker")
  .data(["end"]) // Different link/path types can be defined here
  .enter()
  .append("svg:marker") // This section adds in the arrows
  .attr("id", String)
  .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
  .attr("refX", 15)
  .attr("refY", 0.5)
  .attr("markerWidth", 4)
  .attr("markerHeight", 4)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

//necessary so that zoom knows where to zoom and unzoom from
/* zm.translate([350, 20]); */

root = d3.hierarchy(treeData[0], function(d) {
  return d.children;
});
root.x0 = 0;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

d3.select(".tree-diagram")
  .style("height", "1000px");

// END OF DRAW TREEE //

function update(source) {
  const treeData = treeMap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
    links = treeData.links();

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 90;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.data.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + source.x0 + ', ' + source.y0 + ')')
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("click", click);
  //  .on("blur", onNodeBlur);

  nodeEnter.append('path')
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      if (d.data.type === 'decision') {
        return 'M 60 0 120 30 60 60 0 30 Z';
      } else if (d.data.type === 'action') {
        return 'M 0 0 120 0 120 60 0 60 Z';
      } else {
        return 'M -100 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10Z';
      }
    })
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr('class', 'myPaths')
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return "lightsteelblue";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", rectW / 2)
    .attr("y", rectH / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.name;
    });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (d.x) + "," + (d.y) + ")";
    });


  nodeUpdate.select('path.myPaths')
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      if (d.data.type === 'decision') {
        return 'M 60 0 120 30 60 60 0 30 Z';
      } else if (d.data.type === 'action') {
        return 'M 0 0 120 0 120 60 0 60 Z';
      } else {
        return 'M -100 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10Z';
      }
    });


  var nodeExit = node.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.source.data.id + " " + d.target.data.id;
    })
    .classed('link1', true);


  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter()
    .insert("g", "g")
    .attr("class", "link");

  linkEnter.append('path')
    .on('click', function(d, i) {
      selectedLink = d;
      // Use the native SVG interface to get the bounding box to
      // calculate the center of the path

      var bbox = this.getBBox();
      var x;
      var y;

      if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
        // Child is to the right of the parent
        x = bbox.x + bbox.width;
        y = bbox.y;
        plusButton
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ', ' + y + ')')
          .classed('hide', false);

      } else {
        x = bbox.x;
        y = bbox.y;
        plusButton
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ', ' + y + ')')
          .classed('hide', false);
      }
    })
    .on('blur', function(d, i) {
      plusButton
        .classed('hide', true);
    })
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

  // Add Link Texts.
  linkEnter.append('text');

  // Merge the new and the existing links before setting `d` and `text` on all of them
  link = linkEnter.merge(link);

  link.select('path')
    .attr("d", linkFunc);

  link.select('text')
    .text(function(d, i) {
      if (d.source.x < d.target.x) {
        return 'True';
      } else {
        return 'False';
      }
    })
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
      if (d.source.x < d.target.x && d.target.data.type) {
        return 'translate(' + (d.target.x + rectW / 2) + ',' + (d.source.y + rectH) + ')';
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });


  //LinkUpdate
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", linkFunc);

  // Transition links to their new position.

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", linkFunc)
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}


// ON CLICK OF NODES
function click(d) {

  if (d.data.type === 'action') {
    return;
  }

  selectedNode = d;

  if (!(d.data.children && d.data.children[0] && Object.keys(d.data.children[0]).length)) {
    diamondImageFalse
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (d.x - 20) + ', ' + (d.y + 35) + ')')
      .classed('hide', false);

    rectangleShapeFalse.attr('transform', 'translate(' + (d.x - 20) + ', ' + d.y + ')').classed('hide', false);

  }

  if (!(d.data.children && d.data.children[1] && Object.keys(d.data.children[1]).length)) {
    diamondImage
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (d.x + 110) + ', ' + (d.y + 35) + ')')
      .classed('hide', false);

    rectangleShape.attr('transform', 'translate(' + (d.x + 110) + ', ' + d.y + ')').classed('hide', false);

  }
}

// oN CALL

function addElement(d, truthy) {
  d.children = null;
  d.children = generateEmptyDecisionBox(truthy);
  update(root);
}

// draw elements //

function drawDiamond(centroid) {
  // Start at the top
  var result = 'M' + centroid.x + ',' + (centroid.y - rectH / 2);

  // Go right
  result += 'L' + (centroid.x + rectW / 2) + ',' + centroid.y;

  // Bottom
  result += 'L' + centroid.x + ',' + (centroid.y + rectH / 2);

  // Left
  result += 'L' + (centroid.x - rectW / 2) + ',' + centroid.y;

  // Close the shape
  result += 'Z';

  return result;
}

function drawRect(centroid) {
  // Start at the top left
  var result = 'M' + (centroid.x - rectW / 2) + ',' + (centroid.y - rectH / 2);

  // Go right
  result += 'h' + rectW;

  // Go down
  result += 'v' + rectH;

  // Left
  result += 'h-' + rectW;

  // Close the shape
  result += 'Z';
  return result;
}

var plusButton = svg
  .append('g')
  .classed('button', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    /*        addElement(selectedLink.source); */
    removeAllButtonElements();
  });

plusButton
  .append('rect')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(-8, -8)') // center the button inside the `g`
  .attr('width', 16)
  .attr('height', 16)
  .attr('rx', 2);

plusButton
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', 'M-6 0 H6 M0 -6 V6');

var rectangleShape = svg.append('g')
  .classed('conditionImage', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    addActionOrDecision(selectedNode, 'action', 'True');
    removeAllButtonElements();
  });

rectangleShape
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', 30)
  .attr('height', 20)
  .style('fill', 'orange');


var diamondImage = svg.append('g')
  .classed('conditionSvg', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .classed('scale', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    addActionOrDecision(selectedNode, 'decision', 'True');
    removeAllButtonElements();
  });

diamondImage
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', 'M 15 0 30 15 15 30 0 15 Z')
  .style("fill", 'orange');


var rectangleShapeFalse = svg.append('g')
  .classed('conditionImage', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    addActionOrDecision(selectedNode, 'action', 'False');
    removeAllButtonElements();
  });

rectangleShapeFalse
  .append('rect')
  .attr('width', 30)
  .attr('height', 20)
  .style('fill', 'orange');

var diamondImageFalse = svg.append('g')
  .classed('conditionImage', true)
  .classed('hide', true)
  .classed('scale', true)
  .on('click', function() {
    addActionOrDecision(selectedNode, 'decision', 'False');
    //  addElement(selectedNode, 'False');
    removeAllButtonElements();
  });

diamondImageFalse
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', 'M 15 0 30 15 15 30 0 15 Z')
  .style("fill", 'orange');


function removeAllButtonElements() {
  plusButton.classed('hide', true);
  diamondImage.classed('hide', true);
  rectangleShape.classed('hide', true);
  diamondImageFalse.classed('hide', true);
  rectangleShapeFalse.classed('hide', true);
}


function addActionOrDecision(selectedNode, nodeType, conditionType) {

  const parentNodeId = selectedNode.parent.data.id;
  const selectedNodeId = selectedNode.data.id;

  // find the selected node from the actual treeData
  const foundRule = getNodeFromNodeId(treeData, selectedNodeId);
  const newRuleId = Math.random();

  const newNodeToAdd = {
    "condition": conditionType,
    "name": nodeType === 'decision' ? 'New Decision' : 'New Action',
    "type": nodeType,
    "value": "",
    "id": newRuleId,
    "parent": parentNodeId,
    "children": [],
  };

  const clonedNewNode = { ...newNodeToAdd
  };

  if (conditionType === 'False' && foundRule.children) {
    //    foundRule.children[0] = newNodeToAdd;

    foundRule.children.splice(0, 1, clonedNewNode);

    if (!(foundRule.children[1] && Object.keys(foundRule.children[1]))) {
      foundRule.children[1] = {};
    }

  } else {
    //   foundRule.children[1] = newNodeToAdd;

    foundRule.children.splice(1, 1, clonedNewNode);

    if (!(foundRule.children[0] && Object.keys(foundRule.children[0]))) {
      founRule.children[0] = {};
    }
  }

  // find the node and add a child to it. 
  updateTree();

}

function updateTree() {
  root = d3.hierarchy(treeData[0], function(d) {
    return d.children;
  });
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  update(root);

}

function getNodeFromNodeId(nodes, nodeId) {
  for (const node of nodes) {
    const currNode = node;
    if (currNode) {
      if (currNode.id === nodeId) {
        return currNode;
      } else if (currNode.children) {
        const childResult = getNodeFromNodeId(currNode.children, nodeId);
        if (childResult) {
          return childResult;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none !important;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.button>path {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 1.5;
  /*   outline: none;  */
}

.button>rect {
  fill: #ddd;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.conditionalSvg {
  /*   outline: none; */
  display: none;
}

.hide {
  /*    display: none;  */
  opacity: 0 !important;
  /*  pointer-events: none;  */
}

.link:hover {
  outline: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.link path {
  /*   outline: none !important;  */
  fill: none;
  stroke: darkgray;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.link path:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}

.link text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.colorBlue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="tree-diagram">
</div>
```

---

**EDIT** you were right about wrapping the links around the nodes, since adding a child to the overlapping node should always trigger a relayout. I wrapped the link around it roughly, using just straight corners. You could make that smoother using the `Q` logic around inflections currently contained in `linkFunc`.

Comment: that's really nice! But I see that as soon as I add another node beneath the "NODE HAVING OVERLAP ISSUE" , the left link of it's parent flows into the children. Here is an image of what I am saying :- https://imgur.com/a/rCHelX3

Comment: I've updated my answer, you were right, you should have just wrapped the links around the nodes

Comment: thanks! I was just going through the code and observed that you modified the way links are added to the tree ( instead of using descendants ), was not aware of that, this changed the selectedLink to have a source and target, Looks like I would have to change my logics to adapt to this. Earlier ( d.source.x --> d.parentx , and d.target.x  --> d.x) , Looks like now I have to change these references to "source,target".

Comment: just a quick quesiton here regarding the way I am deleting and adding nodes, do you think this is the right way to do ? I am modifying the actual data and recomputing the entire tree, do you think I should be doing it in a different way ?

Comment: I don't know how to answer that, it's a very opinion-based thing. Just make sure you have a single source of truth (most likely your data). That is more important than whether or not you compute the entire tree

Comment: Hope you are doing good, In this flow chart one thing I observed is that the links are drawn first and then the nodes are being transitioned/animated to their positions , how can I have both links and nodes transition to their positions simultaneously and smoothly ? I've asked a new question for the same here :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65210665/d3-make-links-flow-along-with-nodes-when-tree-loads  , please take a look at it when you find some time. Thanks!